# MQTT msg.payload funny characters

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mqtt, paho

I have a temperature sensor connected to raspberry via MQTT on ESP32 controller, it display correctly temperature in Arduino IDE serial monitor also in Home Assistant webpage.
I am trying to get it display on Raspberry Pi console with a python 3 script.  it display the value but add charachteres --> b' 22.71'

I tried to strip characters or display values from specific position without success.  I need to have only temperature value for export it.

the script is

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, rc, *extra_params):
  client.subscribe("ha/temperature")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
  if msg.topic == 'ha/temperature':
    print(msg.payload)

client = mqtt.Client("test")
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.username_pw_set(username="username",password="password")
client.connect("192.168.0.100", 1883, 60)
client.loop_forever()
```

the result is:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo python3 BasicMQTT.py
b' 22.71'
b' 22.71'
b' 22.71'
b' 22.71'
```

how it can be strip "b" "'" and space characters from output?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because with python3 the paho library is returning a byte array not the string representation of the byte array for the payload.

You can fix changing the `on_message` callback as follows:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
  if msg.topic == 'ha/temperature':
    print(msg.payload.decode("utf-8") )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response